# Remesh spheres in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, remesh

How can i remesh spheres to look like metaballs without destroying my wireframe object? Im trying to make this animation but metaballs are broken and wont render with geometry nodes.[image]

[image]

Comment: I might use a particle system instead of geometry nodes.

Comment: What exactly do you want to remesh here? Unfortunately, the underlying problem is not clear from your question. Please be so kind and edit this question.